# Add timestamp to doublclick ad

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to code this so that the timestamp shows up.

```
<SCRIPT language='JavaScript1.1' SRC="https://ad.doubleclick.net/ddm/adj/abc.def;sz=160x600;ord=[timestamp]?">
</SCRIPT>
```

I know I can grab the timestamp through `Date.now`

```
var timestamp = Date.now();
```

Just not sure how to set the `ord=[timestamp]` to the current timestamp.  I'm new to js - I'm sure this is pretty simple but I just can't get anything to work.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If file is PHP, you can try using it by substituing `[timestamp]` to `<?php echo strtotime('now'); ?>`

Comment: You cannot do that with js as-is. You will either need to either `document.write()` the script tag or dynamically append it to DOM to be able to use the js variable. If you want the script on the page as shown, you will need to populate it server-side (e.g. with php)